# filtering multiple dates across database in sql?

Tags: sql, database

I have a database that I am trying to filter out by time stamped dates. Since the dates occur over a 15 year time span, I want to filter everything by month (ex all of the january data together). I also have other conditions to filter data, but the logic is getting screwed up when I filter things doing 
ex)

```
where x=y
and id.number=165
and {id.date between UNIX_DATE('01-01-2015') and UNIX_DATE('31-01-2015') 
     or id.date between UNIX_DATE('01-01-2016') and UNIX_DATE(-31-01-2016')}
```

I know I can't break it into that braced condition, since it returns an error for me. Is there a way to group the conditions together so the logic is conditionA AND conditionB AND (dateyearA OR dateyearB OR dateyearC or....)?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You have to extract month in your select and group them. Which database?

Comment: It's a confidential database unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The ANSI SQL standard provides a way of extracting the month from a date.  You should use that:

```
where x = y and
     id.number = 165 and
     extract(month from id.date) = 1
```

That should greatly simplify your code.  Not all databases support `extract()`.  Most support either `extract()` or the `month()` function.  All have this functionality using some function.